# How to reset a flutter Page (Widget) to initial state(state when the app was first Built)

Tags: flutter, dart

Let's say I have a few sliders and switches on my page, I change their state and modify them, I understand that we do `setState` to show the changed state of the widget tree and rebuild it, but I would like to know if there's a way to undo all those changes and go back to the initial state (state the app was when it was first built)?
I don't want to call a custom function which manually resets the variables to initial values. Nor the routes should be removed and added back (because it would show the transition)

Comment: if you initialize all your state in initState you can call it again in the same way you call setState :)

Comment: looking for an answer from a reputable source.That shows the right way of doing it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**If you want to do things out of the box**

[image]

---

#### Short answer:

Use any of the below:

```dart
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/currentRoute');
Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/currentRoute');
```

#### Long answer:

```dart
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: DummyWidget()));

class DummyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => HomePage();
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool _enabled = false; // For Switch
  double _value = 0; // For Slider

  // This is the trick!
  void _reset() {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      PageRouteBuilder(
        transitionDuration: Duration.zero,
        pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => DummyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Switch(
            value: _enabled,
            onChanged: (newValue) => setState(() => _enabled = newValue),
          ),
          Slider(
            value: _value,
            onChanged: (newValue) => setState(() => _value = newValue),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: _reset,
            child: Text('RESET'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

A better approach might be with keys. Here's the [key approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64183322/6618622)

Answer (score 8):

A simple trick would be to pop and push with the same route. Like this:

```
Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, "same_route");
```

Answer (score 6):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

Using `key` to change the state.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: KeyedSubtree(
        key: ValueKey<int>(_count),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            MainPage(),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => setState(() => ++_count),
              child: Text('RESET'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  bool _enabled = false; // For Switch
  double _value = 0; // For Slider.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Switch(
          value: _enabled,
          onChanged: (newValue) => setState(() => _enabled = newValue),
        ),
        Slider(
          value: _value,
          onChanged: (newValue) => setState(() => _value = newValue),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens to the widgets with old keys? Do they get GCed ?

Comment: It was the best approach for me, that I had an inner Component that I had to reset all animations every time I changed an input in the parent component.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of many to reset to the initial data

[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

List<String> initialData = ['First', 'Second', 'Third'];

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: Example(),
    );
  }
}

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  List<String> items = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    fillInitialData();
    super.initState();
  }

  fillInitialData() {
    items.addAll(initialData);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Example')),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Card(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Text(items[index]),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    items.add('A new item');
                  });
                },
                child: Text('Add an item'),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    items.clear();
                    fillInitialData();
                  });
                },
                child: Text('Reset'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer is more specific to your usecase and data structure I am looking for a general way to reset a page activity

Comment: it is the same idea, declare variables, assign initial values then reset when needed. if you want to reset a widget completely, you may call `setState` from its parent and pass your initial data. `Example(name: 'maheshmnj', awards: [...])`. as i said there are many ways to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Full Code:**

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      // Passing initial values
      home: HomePage(enabled: false, value: 0),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool enabled;
  final double value;

  HomePage({this.enabled = false, this.value = 0});

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool _initialEnabled, _enabled; // For Switches
  double _initialValue, _value; // For Sliders

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Assign them once (initial data)
    _initialEnabled ??= widget.enabled;
    _initialValue ??= widget.value;

    // These values can be changed by respective widgets
    _enabled = _initialEnabled;
    _value = _initialValue;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Switch(
              value: _enabled,
              onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _enabled = value),
            ),
            Slider(
              value: _value,
              onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _value = value),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  // Resetting the values to initial ones which were passed
                  _enabled = _initialEnabled;
                  _value = _initialValue;
                });
              },
              child: Text('RESET'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of age-old design patterns that might be useful in this situation. Having a reset option is cool, but what's cooler is *undo*.

See how the *Command* and *Memento* patterns can be implemented in Flutter with these tutorials: [Command](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-design-patterns-12-command-e199172e16eb) | [Memento](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4074597-getting-started-with-the-bloc-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

You can call `YourStateClass.initState()` to revert to its original initialized state.

Also make sure that when you construct your state, you will want to initialize all of your variables in the `void initState()` function.

ex.

```
class FooState extends State<Foo> { 
    int someVariable;

    @override
    void initState() {
        someVariable = 0;
    }
}
```

You need to have all of your variables assigned a value in the `initState()` function in order for this to work.

For more info check out the docs at: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html

Comment: `final`s cannot be reassigned. It should be `int someVariable;`.

Comment: This did not work for me. Using PageRouteBuilder did the work